# Argument of type '"openURL"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never' using Jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, jestjs

I am beginner in Jest and these are classes defined.
APIService class is not exported; only openURL function is defined.

APIService.ts

```
    export const openURL = async (openURL : string) => {
    await Linking.openURL(openURL );
};
```

RegistrationPage.tsx

```
import{openURL} from '../APIService';
```

RegistrationPage.test.ts

```
test('should call function openURL with empty value', async () => {
const url = '';
const mockOpenURL = jest.fn();
mockOpenURL .mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(''));
const openURLSpy = jest.spyOn(openURL, 'openURL');
const mockURL = await openURL(url);
expect(mockOpenURL).toBeCalled();
expect(mockURL).toEqual(url);
expect(mockOpenURL).toHaveBeenCalledWith(url);
openURLSpy.mockRestore();
```

});

After writing this function as per my understating may be it has loopholes not having properly mocked or spyed
running it causing an error for Argument of type '"openURL"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never' using Jest

suggestions to improve this testcase will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just defining a variable locally like `const mockOpenURL = jest.fn()` cannot mock anything.

`jest.spyOn(openURL, 'openURL')` fails because `openURL` is a function and there's there's no `openURL.openURL` property.

It's `APIService` module that needs to be mocked:

```
import{openURL} from '../APIService';
jest.mock('../APIService', () => {
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    openURL: jest.fn()
  }
};
...
openURL.mockResolvedValue();
// code that calls openURL
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing this doubt @Estus Flask. and May I know why it is written over there  __esModule: true ?

Comment: You're welcome. See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options . `__esModule` is needed for named export, otherwise a mock is considered CommonJS module, so mocked module export is treated as ES module `default`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @
jest.mock('../APIService.ts', () => {
return {
__esModule: true,
openURL: jest.fn(),
};
});

```
test('openURL function to be called with', async () => {
    const openURL = 'www.google.com';
    const openURL = jest.fn();
    openURL.mockReturnValue(openURL );
  });
```